# PCSX not loading after new game start

Tags: 12.04, iso, emulation

I am running pcsx on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, and I tried running Chrono Cross as an .iso file. As soon as I start the new game, the screen goes black and it does not load. Any advice?

I installed pcsx from the software center.

It freezes with all games.

I will try the info from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=159987) and see what happens.

It looks really helpful...updates to follow.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Did you follow along with this thread? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=159987 did you install from package or source?  We need details...  Is it only the one game or all games?

Comment: I installed it from the software center. It freezes with all games. I will try the info in that thread and see what happens. Thanks though, looks really helpful....i will let you know what happens

Comment: good deal.  if you would, update it in the question as an edit in the future...

Comment: Yess, PCSX with libstdc++5 works fine, i'm happy :)
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by installing libstdc++5. After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had more luck using RetroArch than PCSX to emulate playstation games on Ubuntu. You need to convert the ISO files to CUE files though, which is not too hard.

See my full guide here: 
http://butlerpc.net/blog/2015/07/guide-to-running-retroarch-playstation-emulator-on-ubuntu-14-04/

or this linked SO question: 
[Trouble installing PCSX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650300/i-am-having-ungodly-trouble-installing-pcsx-can-anyone-keep-me-from-popping-out/650304)